# com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer on 4.4.4 device (works on 7.0.1)

Tags: android, exception

I have got a problem with getting data from web service to spinner using volley.My problem is the same thing worked in **Android 7.0.1 (emulator)** but not in **Android 4.4 (real device)** what can I do now.Please help me out.
My code is this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener{

    //Declaring an Spinner
    private Spinner spinner;

    //An ArrayList for Spinner Items
    private ArrayList<String> students;

    //JSON Array
    private JSONArray result;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;

    //TextViews to display details
    private TextView textViewName;
    private TextView textViewCourse;
    private TextView textViewSession;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initializing the ArrayList
        students = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Initializing Spinner
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        //Adding an Item Selected Listener to our Spinner
        //As we have implemented the class Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener to this class iteself we are passing this to setOnItemSelectedListener
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Initializing TextViews


        //This method will fetch the data from the URL
        getData();
    }

    private void getData(){


        //Creating a request queue

        JsonObjectRequest StringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Config.DATA_URL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        if (response != null) {
                            JSONObject j = null;
                            try {
                                //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                                j = response;

                                //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                                result = j.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

                                //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                                getStudents(result);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        System.out.println("Volly error is this >>" + error);



                    }

                });
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN
                && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            HttpStack stack = null;
            try {
                stack = new HurlStack(null, new TLSSocketFactory());
            } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Your Wrapper Class", "Could not create new stack for TLS v1.2");
                stack = new HurlStack();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Your Wrapper Class", "Could not create new stack for TLS v1.2");
                stack = new HurlStack();
            }
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(), stack);
        } else {
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

       requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(StringRequest);
    }


    private void getStudents(JSONArray j){
        //Traversing through all the items in the json array
        for(int i=0;i<j.length();i++){
            try {
                //Getting json object
                JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

                //Adding the name of the student to array list
                students.add(json.getString(Config.TAG_USERNAME));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Log.e("student >>",students.toString());
        //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, students));
    }

    //Method to get student name of a particular position


    //this method will execute when we pic an item from the spinner
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Setting the values to textviews for a selected item

    }

    //When no item is selected this method would execute
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

I've had an issue similar to this whereby my API calls would work in newer versions of Android (21 and up I think), but not in older ones. This is due to a newer version of SSL only being supported in the newer versions of Android.

To overcome this problem we have to a bit more set up when initialising the Volley Request Queue:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN
            && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        HttpStack stack = null;
        try {
            stack = new HurlStack(null, new TLSSocketFactory());
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Your Wrapper Class", "Could not create new stack for TLS v1.2");
            stack = new HurlStack();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Your Wrapper Class", "Could not create new stack for TLS v1.2");
            stack = new HurlStack();
        }
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, stack);
    } else {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    }
```

**TLSSocketFactory**

```
public class TLSSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

private SSLSocketFactory internalSSLSocketFactory;

public TLSSocketFactory() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(null, null, null);
    internalSSLSocketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
}

@Override
public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
    return internalSSLSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
}

@Override
public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
    return internalSSLSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
}

private Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
    if(socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
        ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});
    }
    return socket;
}
}
```

Add the `TLSSocketFactory` class to your project and it should work flawlessly.

Comment: apply code still not working.Please view edit.And response

Comment: It works fine - you'll just need to add the imports.

Comment: volley HttpStack is now deprecated. any idea on a different approach to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

```
private void updateAndroidSecurityProvider() {
   try {
       ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.getMessage();
   }
}
```

call above method before calling any HTTP .

and

added below library in gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0
```

Comment: Thanks, Please change gradle dependency to implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

Comment: @saeid Please up-vote, if this answer is useful to you.